# Vue Router - Invalid navigation guard error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, vue-router

I have a navigation guard that has an issue, the IDE keeps complaining that **requiresAuth** is an unresolved variable

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next)=>{
    if(to.matched.some((record)=> record.meta.requiresAuth)){
        const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
        if(await currentUser){
            next()
        }
        else{
            next("/about")
        }
    }
});
```

And this is my router, where the second route has the meta object that contains the requiresAuth property that is unresolved.

```
const router = createRouter({
    history:createWebHistory(),
    routes:[
        {
            path:"/",
            name:"Home",
            component:Home,
        },
        {
            path:"/dashboard",
            component: Dashboard,
            meta:{
                requiresAuth:true,
            }
        }

    ]
})
```

The error that i get in the console when i start up the app is the following

`Error: Invalid navigation guard at vue-router.mjs:2008:47`

The code doesn't run past the first if statement in the beforeEach hook so the issue is the requiresAuth.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the issue is the fact that not all paths of your navigation guard call `next()`

All of your code is wrapped in a single `if` statement. If that first `if` statement is not true, then vue-router doesn't know what to do.

```js
router.beforeEach(...) {
  if (to.matched...) {
    if(user) {
      next()
    } else {
      next('/about')
    }
  }
  // Error here
}
```

These types of mistakes are exactly why using `next` is [not really recommended](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#optional-third-argument-next) and is only *optionally* supported at this point in vue-router 4.

The fix however is quite simple.  Outside of that first if statement, the very last line of code should be another call to `next()`

Comment: This guard suggest there should be `else next()` in the place of "Error here". Or better replace next with return statements that make control flow less error-prone in this case.

Comment: This stops the error yes, but it doesn't fix the issue which is that the meta objects requiresAuth property is unresolved
thank you for the info `next()`, i did not know about that